# Homogeneity of vertex values in a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $\mathbf{g}$ be a finite connected graph. For any vertex $i$ of $\mathbf{g}$, we may define a real number $x_i$ which is some strict convex combination of the $x$'s of the vertices adjacent to it:
$$  x_i = \sum_{j \in N_i} w_j x_j \hspace{1cm} \forall i,j : w_j > 0 , \sum_{j \in N_i} w_j = 1 $$

where $N_i = \{ j \neq i \mid ij \in \mathbf{g} \}$.

**Claim.** For all vertices $i,j$ in $\mathbf{g}$, $x_i = x_j$.

*Proof.* Let $i$ be a vertex with the minimum $x$. Then there must be some $j$ such that $ij \in \mathbf{g}$ and $x_i < x_j$. But then there must be some $k$ such that $x_k < x_i$,  a contradiction.

The claim follows immediately. QED

Is this proof sound?

Comment: With $N_i$ do you denote the neighbors of vertex $i$ in the graph $\mathbf{g}$?

If so, why $N_{v_1}=v_2$?

Comment: You're right, I've substantially corrected the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great reasoning, but that's how I would run it.

So let $i$ be a vertex with the smallest label $x_i$.
Then $x_k\geq x_i$ for all $k\in N_i$. If there exists $j\in N_i$ that $x_j>x_i$, then
$$
x_i=\sum_{k\in N_i}w_kx_k>\sum_{k\in N_i}w_kx_i=x_i\sum_{k\in N_i}w_k=x_i.
$$
Contradiction.